# What qualities should I look for when choosing a phone for development?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm looking to get a windows phone to use as a development platform.  What should I consider when comparing models?  I'm not interested in opinions about individual phones, but about what  features I should make sure exist.

Comment: This is *barely* on topic now.  For further info about just how hard it is to write a good question like this, check out [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend one with gyroscope and front facing camera, to be able to test the features of the last WP7 handsets. But overall, it's pretty good to develop on the slowest phone you can find. This way, you make sure that your app will provide good user experience on pretty much all available devices.

Comment: Due to this answer, I'm going to have to reopen and reword OP's question.  Thanks.  I blame you and your good answer entirely.